# Plotly adding two sliders in python

Tags: slider, plotly-python

I have read plotly slider instruction:https://plotly.com/python/sliders/, but still can't find a way to create two sliders in one graph. I'm new to plotly so any kind of advice will be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently it's not possible (see [plotly community post](https://community.plotly.com/t/two-slider-controls-for-single-plot-with-two-parameters/13900/3)) - but since this post is from '18, there might be a solution by now (that I'm not aware of).
If you are working in a Jupyter notebook, you could use FigureWidget (as suggested in the post) as follows:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go 
import numpy as np

def linear_function(a,b,x):
    return a*x+b

a0 = 0.1
b0 = 0.1
x = np.arange(-10,10,0.1)

data = [go.Scatter(x=x,y=linear_function(a=a0,b=b0,x=x))]

fig = go.FigureWidget(data=data)
fig.update_yaxes(autorange=False,range=(-3,3))

@interact(a=(0, 1, 0.1), b=(0, 1, 0.1))
def update(a=a0, b=b0):
    with fig.batch_update():
        fig.data[0].y = linear_function(a=a,b=b,x=x)
    return fig
```

However, there is sometimes a significant delay in rendering when using interact. Therefore, I would like to point out that in many cases it may be the better solution to fix one variable and only set the other variable interactively:

```
# Fixing a
a = 0.1

fig = go.Figure()
fig.update_layout(title = f"Linear function a*x+b with a fixed at {a} and b adjustable")
fig.update_yaxes(autorange=False,range=(-3,3))
parameters = np.arange(0, 5, 0.1)

for b in parameters:
    fig.add_trace(
        go.Scatter(
            visible=False,
            x=x,
            y=linear_function(a=a,b=b,x=x),
        ))

# Make 0th trace visible
fig.data[0].visible = True

# Create and add slider
steps = []
for i in range(len(fig.data)):
    step = dict(
        method="update",
        label=f"{parameters[i]: .2f}",
        args=[{"visible": [False] * len(fig.data)}],  
    )
    step["args"][0]["visible"][i] = True  
    steps.append(step)

sliders = [dict(
    active=0,
    pad={"t": 50},
    steps=steps
)]

fig.update_layout(
    sliders=sliders
)

fig.show()
```

I hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

At the part of that tutorial where you set the `sliders` variable, notice that it is being set to a *list*. You can have multiple dictionaries inside this list defining all of your sliders. By default, they will all be placed on top of each other, but you can utilize the `pad` key inside the dictionary to add padding to the sliders as needed in order to space them out. For example, here is how you'd add two sliders:

```py
sliders = [
    dict(
        currentvalue={"prefix": "Initial Velocity: ", "suffix": " m/s"},
        steps=steps,
        active=0,
        pad=dict(b=120),
    ),
    dict(
        currentvalue={"prefix": "Initial Position: ", "suffix": " m"},
        steps=steps,
        active=0,
        pad=dict(t=120),
    ),
]
                                                                         
fig.update_layout(sliders=sliders)
```

The `b` and `t` keys inside of the `pad` dictionary correspond to the amount of padding, in pixels, to add to the bottom and top of the slider, respectively. There are also `l` and `r` arguments.

[The sliders reference](https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/sliders/) is a useful resource.